# URL rewrite regex to allow alphanumeric underscores and hyphens

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I currently have the regex to allow underscore how do I add the hyphen in?

Here is what I have currently.

```
^(\w+)[/]*$
```

Which I believe the *$ equates to the underscore?

Comment: An underscore is just `_`. It's included in `\w`. The * is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and the $ means the end of the line. http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html will give you an excellent start on understanding regexes.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMorgan Ill be honest, looking at regex makes my brain hurt :D Ill try my bestest though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([\w-]+)/*$
```

And underscore is there because of `\w` which means word characters that includes all alphabets, all digits and underscore.

Comment: Some regex engines will choke on that `/` unless you escape it.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Agreed if your platform doesn't support an alternative character other than  `/` as regex boundary (PHP, PERL, sed etc allow that) then `/` needs to be escaped as in `/^([\w-]+)\/*$/`